# How to read all the files of a directory in python and save file data in a dictionary

Tags: python, csv, txt

I have many documents in a folder. They in thousands in a .txt format. I want to read all of those documents and want to store documents content in a dictionary. The key of dictionary can be documents name and value should be content of that particular document. But right now I am only able to print all the names of my files but not able to make a dictionary where its content can be stored. I have written this code:

```
import os
with os.scandir('docs/') as entries:
    for entry in entries:
        print(entry.name)
        with open('F:\folder\docs\'+entry.name) as f:
            contents = {'entry.name': f.read()}
```

Or if you can give me some new method to read content from all the files and then store it in a dictionary. Please help me in this regard. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way it should work.

```
import os

docs_dict = {}

with os.scandir('docs/') as entries:
    for entry in entries:
        print(entry.name)
        with open('F:/folder/docs/'+ entry.name ) as f:
          val = f.read()
          docs_dict[f.name] = val
          f.close()
```

I created an empty dictionary outside the `for` loop. Then, expanding your code, I stored the content of the document in `val` and then added the dictionary item. I also changed `F:\folder\docs\` to `F:/folder/docs/`, cause Python wants forward slashes in paths, and using `\` excludes the ending quote of the string.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Your code worked for me. Only problem is f.name is giving absolute path. Is there any way that only file name should come instead of that path

Comment: Glad that you find it useful. If you replace "f.name" with "entry.name" you should end up with the file name as your dictionary key

Comment: Hi, I have posted another question. Would you like to help me in that questions as well? Its link is as follow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64573033/how-to-remove-punctuation-from-a-list

Answer (score 0):

assuming the loop in the code you have posted works - the code below should create the dict you are looking for.

```
import os
data = {}
with os.scandir('docs/') as entries:
    for entry in entries:
        with open('F:\folder\docs\'+entry.name) as f:
            data[entry.name] = f.read()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but it is giving me an Syntax error: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: Second last line. Notebook giving an arrow below the f:

Comment: Hi, I have created another question. Would you like to help me in that question as well? You can find that question on this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64573033/how-to-remove-punctuation-from-a-list

Answer (score 0):

my solution:

```
import os
import json


all_files = dict()
with os.scandir() as entries:
    for entry in entries:
        print(entry.name)
        with open(rf'{entry.name}') as f:
            contents = f.read()
        all_files[f'{entry.name}'] = contents
        
with open('all_files.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(all_files, f, indent=2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can you please let me know why you have written last two lines and why are you writing those files.

Comment: they are creating a json file that will store dictionary in it, then you can easily access the dictionary by loading it without the need to always create a new dict

Comment: Hi, I have created another question. Would you like to help me in that question as well? You can find that question on this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64573033/how-to-remove-punctuation-from-a-list